# Adding Tomcat 7 Plugin to Flex Builder 3

Tags: tomcat, apache-flex, tomcat7, flex3, flexbuilder

Is there anyway we can add the tomcat 7 plugin to Adobe Flex Builder 3?

Answer (score -1):

Install eclipse for java ee developers (or any version with WTP plugins) then you can both add flex builder as a plugin and tomcat plugin..

Comment: the flex builder plugin for eclipse has been officially disowned and deprecated by Adobe.Marking as stale information.

Comment: no it is not abondoned, the plugin and standalone packages had been converted into a single file which you can install as a plugin or standalone.